# Как задать css модели в Django?

Tags: html, python, django, model, django-view

models.py:

```
...
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = " ")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
...
```

templates/newpost.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py:

```
...
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'tags']
...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это выглядит *ужасно*. Как задать стиль?

Comment: Подключаешь стили в шаблон. В чем трудность?..

Comment: Подключаете стили обычным способом. Чтобы сформировать `href` на `HOST/STATIC_URL/` подключайте так: `{% load static %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">`.

Comment: Я использую bootstrap и хочу указать класс для форм.

Comment: Так покажите нам код своих форм (не шаблонов)

Comment: Так у меня нету кода форм я генерирую их по шаблонам `<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>`

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, покажите тогда код вашей view, которая отдает контекст в шаблон

Comment: Добавил views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static/css/base.css:

```css
...
#id_body{
    /*some style for the body of form*/
    ...

}
#id_title{
    /*some style for the title of form*/
    ...
}
#id_tags{...}
#id_author{...}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Подключите нужные стили в `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><a href="/">Home</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  {% block content %}
                  {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это ясно , вопрос был другой: как задать код форме которая генерируется по коду модели и view, и я уже нашел ответ...